# What is my problem with the implementation of multivariate_gauss pdf?

Tags: python, numpy, math, gaussian

I use python to calculate the multivariate_gauss distribution, but I don't know what's wrong.
The code is here

```
# calculate multi-d gaussian pdf
def mul_gauss(x, mu, sigma) -> float:
    d = len(x[0])
    front = 1 / math.sqrt(((2 * math.pi) ** d) * np.linalg.det(sigma))
    tmp = (np.array(x) - np.array(mu))
    tmp_T = np.transpose(tmp)
    back = -0.5 * (np.matmul(np.matmul(tmp, np.linalg.inv(sigma)), tmp_T))[0][0]
    return front * math.exp(back)
```

I compared the result with scipy.stats.multivariate_normal(x,mu,sigma)

```
x = [[2,2]]
mu = [[4,4]]
sigma = [[3,0],[0,3]]
ret_1 = mul_gauss(x, mu, sigma)
ret_2 = scipy.stats.multivariate_normal(x[0], mu[0], sigma).pdf(x[0])
print('ret_1=',ret1)
print('ret_2=',ret2)
```

and output is
ret_1=0.013984262505331654
ret_2=0.03978873577297383

Could anyone help me?

Comment: It seems everything is correct. In fact playing around with the scipy stats multivariate normal pdf method I realized something I dont understand. If you try for example x = [[2,2]] and mu = [[2,2]] and x = [[4,4]] and mu = [[4,4]] it returns different values! Otherwise your code returns the correct one as far as I understand. So the pdf method is the one I think is doing something weird

Comment: @GonzaloPolo  Actually, when I used 3-d situation such as x = [[a,b,c]] and mu=[[d,e,f]], my code returns value which is bigger than 1 . But that is impossible. So I think my code has some problems indeed but I can't find it.

Comment: Even inserting a positive definite covariance matrix as input? I cant reproduce it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In line 5 of your main you call the `.pdf()` on the object instead as a method.
Here is a fix:

```
# calculate multi-d gaussian pdf
import math

import numpy as np
from scipy import stats


def mul_gauss(x, mu, sigma) -> float:
    d = x[0].shape[0]
    coeff = 1/np.sqrt((2 * math.pi) ** d * np.linalg.det(sigma))
    tmp = x - mu
    exponent = -0.5 * (np.matmul(np.matmul(tmp, np.linalg.inv(sigma)), tmp.T))[0][0]
    return coeff * math.exp(exponent)


x = np.array([[2,2]])
mu = np.array([[4,4]])
sigma = np.array([[3,0],[0,3]])
ret_1 = mul_gauss(x, mu, sigma)
ret_2 = stats.multivariate_normal.pdf(x[0], mu[0], sigma)
print('ret_1=',ret_1)
print('ret_2=',ret_2)
```

Output:

```
ret_1= 0.013984262505331654
ret_2= 0.013984262505331658
```

Cheers.

Comment: When I try this case:
    x = [[2,2]]
    mu = [[4,4]]
    sigma = [[3,1],[2,3]]
the result is still different
ret_1=0.025528112117341697
ret_2=0.03198155263310794
Do i need to make them independent?

Comment: And I try a 4-d case:
    x = [[5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2]]
    mu = [[5.005999999999999, 3.4180000000000006, 1.464, 0.2439999999999999]]
    sigma = [[0.12424897959183676, 0.10029795918367343, 0.01613877551020407, 0.010546938775510202],
             [0.10029795918367343, 0.14517959183673468, 0.01168163265306121, 0.011436734693877546],
             [0.01613877551020407, 0.01168163265306121, 0.03010612244897958, 0.00569795918367347],
             [0.010546938775510202, 0.011436734693877546, 0.00569795918367347, 0.011493877551020406]]
The pdf is bigger than 1. Is that possible?

Comment: @Whipser, you have to always check that the sigma covariance matrix is positive definite. In your comment the matrix sigma[[3,1], [2,3]] is not even symmetric so it is no PD (Positive Definitive). To check that a Matrix is PD is that all its eigenvalues are > 0.

Comment: @GonzaloPolo I check the definition of multivariate gauss and I don't find the PD requirement. So the PD requirement is just for the scipy library or I missed some information?

Comment: @Whipser, the thing is that  the same way that in 1D Normal Distribution you assume that the variance parameter is positive (that is even called "sigma square", it is the variance of the random variable) , for the multivariable Normal this is equivalent to say that the Covariance Matrix is PD (it is the Covariance of the various Random variables that compose the different dimenions). I do not know the scipy code so it might not be checking this either. Try it with 1D to see what happens when you input a negative variance. Hope that helps